# CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.7.0.2 conflicts with:community/Find_Feed 1.0.8

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am using magento **1.5.1.0 CE**, i want to upgrade this to latest version(1.7.0.2). There are many custom modules are there in my store. And want to preserve the data in db which is using now. To check upgrade first i set my store in local(using WAMP) and tried upgrade using **Magento connect manager**. The steps i followed is as folows.

- 1) In connect manager extension key field filled with **connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest**.
- 2) Press install button which gives the overview of available updates.
- 3) Press proceed button.

Some packages installed successfully, But finally throw an error

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.7.0.2 conflicts with:community/Find_Feed 1.0.8
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.5.0.1
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.5.0.1
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.5.0.1
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.5.0.1
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.3 conflicts with: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.5.0.0, community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.5.0.1.
```

Why this is happening? Any one can suggest the best method to upgrade the store safely?